# swipe effect with jQuery [for touch]

Tags: jquery, touch, iphone

I want to create a touch prototype for a mobile web app and I need to implement the iPhone swipe effect (touch).

Does anyone have any idea on any jQuery plugins that I can use directly?? I have the markup as

```
<ul id="body">
   <li class="item">1</li>
   <li class="item">2</li>
   <li class="item">3</li>
   <li class="item">4</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to implement the swipe on the list items

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). They are moving unbelievably fast and support native-like interfaces on several platforms. The swipe effect is just one of many tricks up its sleeve.

Comment: I've searching for the swipe effect. I can't seem to get it there. :/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what sort of swipe effect you're looking for. Can be more specific?

Comment: swipe.. as in what happens in the iPhone Home Screen.. going from one window to another when you've lots of apps installed

Comment: That's the default transition animation for jQuery Mobile pages. You're probably not seeing them because they rely on CSS3 transitions - try using a WebKit browser (Chrome, Safari, or, you know, an iPhone/Android device).